# array_search not working in multi dimensional array as expected

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array (array below) and I am trying to get the key of the value of the sub-array.

```
$array = array(
  'USD' => array (
      0 => 1.79,
      1 => 3.58,
      2 => 5.37,
      3 => 7.16,
      4 => 8.95,
    ),
  'CAD' =>  array (
      0 => 2.49,
      1 => 4.98,
      2 => 7.47,
      3 => 9.96,
      4 => 12.45,
    ),
  'EUR' =>  array (
      0 => 1.99,
      1 => 3.98,
      2 => 5.97,
      3 => 7.96,
      4 => 9.95,
    )
);  
$item_to_get = array_search(5.97, $array);
```

CURRENT OUTPUT

```
false
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT => the parent key name

```
EUR
```

Comment: I think `array_search` works only on one dimensional array...btw what happen if multiple value are the same??

Comment: The result is exactly as expected considering the documentation of the function: it searches through the values inside the array, _not throught the elements of the arrays values_.

Comment: And in order to achieve expected output, i ran out of ideas.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472779/recursive-array-search

Comment: @arkascha Worked fine with a bit of adapting http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b3f38c4556f0be57901037eaf5977747ee1fd35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_search` function is not recursive, so you have to iterate over the array and search in the subarrays:

```
$foundInParent = false;
foreach($array as $parentKey => $subArray) {
  if (array_search(5.97, $subArray)) {
    $foundInParent = $parentKey;
    break;
  }
}

echo $foundInParent;
```

Just wrap it in a function..

Comment: I get null http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/efb4f8d940b2743991c8c2bed3e78aba91729c7b

Comment: @Adrian you need to RETURN the value ;)
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/489dd44aaddce8a1470abd33503101ffd9ebdcfc

Comment: Ah Yes, wasn't attentive.

Comment: @Adrian just a tip, when you create a function first define the return value and put the return statement at the end.. and then start writing your logic in between..

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way `array_search()` is supposed to work - see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

You probably need `array_walk()` with a custom callback function. Or use `foreach()` to iterate over the outer array, then `array_search()` inside the foreach-loop.

I any case, I recommend setting up the array differently in the first place!