# PHP loop through nested JSON to find value

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I am trying to loop through nested JSON data to find a name with a specific string and extract the string value associated with that. In this case the name string is "myKey" and the value string is "12345678".

After looking at several similar questions and documentation, I have tried different approaches such as doing it with objects or associative arrays, but still end up not being able to get to the information I want or receive errors.

Types of errors:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Trying to get property of non-object
```

Here is a snippet of the decoded JSON using $myObj = json_decode($result);

```
object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
  ["info"]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (10) {
    .
    .
    .
  }
  ["stuff"]=>
  array(1) {
    .
    .
    .
  }
  ["result"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#7 (3) {
      ["name"]=>
      ["value"]=>
      ["description"]=>
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#8 (2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Units"
      ["value"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(6) {
          [0]=>
          object(stdClass)#9 (3) {
            .
            .
            .
          }
          .
          .
          .
          [5]=>
          object(stdClass)#14 (2) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(10) "Components"
            ["value"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              array(14) {
                [0]=>
                object(stdClass)#15 (3) {
                .
                .
                .
                }
                [1]=>
                object(stdClass)#16 (3) {
                  ["name"]=>
                  string(5) "myKey"
                  ["value"]=>
                  string(8) "12345678"
                  ["description"]=>
                }
                .
                .
                .
```

Here is a snippet of the PHP code I tried:

```
$myObj = json_decode($result);
// or I have tried
// $myObj = json_decode($result, true);


// here are different snippets of code I tried
foreach($myObj->result as $test) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($test->name);
    echo "<br>";
    if ($test->name == "Units") {
        $resultName = $test->name;
        echo $resultName . "<br>";
    }
    echo '</pre>';
}

/*
foreach($myObj->result as $test) {
    echo $test . "<br>";
    foreach($test->name as $test1) {
        echo $test1 . "<br>";
        foreach($test1->value as $test2) {
            echo $test2 . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
*/

/*
foreach($myObj->result as $test) {
    if (($test->name) == "Units") {
        // grab the value that corresponds to the name
        $units = $test->name;
        if (($units->name) == "Components") {
            $components = $units->name;
            print_r($components);
        }
    }
}
*/
```

I can access what I need directly, by saying:

```
print_r($myObj->result[1]->value[0][5]->value[0][1]->name);
print_r($myObj->result[1]->value[0][5]->value[0][1]->value);
```

but the location of the value may vary, so I need to find the names of the objects by looping

Can anyone provide a better approach using objects (or possibly even associative arrays)?

#### UPDATED TO INCLUDE SNIPPET OF ORIGINAL JSON (before decode)

```
string(21420) "{
  "info": {
  .
  .
  .
  },
  "stuff": [{
    "name":
    "type":
    .
    .
    .
  }],
  "result": [
    {
      "name":
      "value":
      "description":
    },
    {
      "name": "Units",
      "value": [
        [
          {
            "name":
            "value":
            "description":
          },
          .
          .
          .
          {
            "name": "Components",
            "value": [
             [
               {
                 "name":
                 "value":
                 "description":
               },
               {
                 "name": "myKey",
                 "value": "12345678",
                 "description":
               },
               .
               .
               .
             ] (end inner Components value)
           ] (end outer Components value)
         ] (end inner Units value)
       ] (end outer Units value)
     } (end results Units)
   ] (end result)
 } (end opening)
```

Comment: have you considered turning this result into a new (associative) array so you can manage keys/position and make an easy to loop through array?

Comment: Uhm I only see that $result is an array(3), not an object.

Comment: @Adder the result is an array of objects ;)

Comment: can you post a sample of the original json you have to convert?

Comment: @Eineki I have updated the post to show a snippet of the original JSON before the json_decode function

Comment: @sietse85 Are you talking about putting the decoded JSON (objects) into an associate array or decoding the JSON to an associative array to begin with?

Comment: you could use the result as it is now to form a new array with no nesting in it. but Omars anwers is probably a better suggestion

Comment: @Eric No pun intended, really. I appreciate the effort you put in this answer but you have to walk the last mile. I know it is difficult to write a significative json fragment and I am sympatetic with your situation but you have to help us to help you (I do not now, for example, if the `[[` is an array of array or a typo, and no one of them is closed). I should have half an our of time to dedicate to your question but I do not want to spend it reworking the input (hint: do a json mockup by hand or, at least, use var_export to dump your vars instead than var_dump).

Comment: @Eineki I tried to adjust the JSON output to close all the braces as best as I can. The '[[' does indicate an array of array. I wish I could just post all of the data, but there is too much. Basically the data is an object that has an array of array of array.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you need some recursive function (a function that calls itself until it finds the the result) to find the value within the nested array.

Take a look at [Recursive array_search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472779/recursive-array-search)

Of course you will have to change the function in that question, but I have similar issue once and it was very userful.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for encoding and decoding. hope this helps you

```
 //Encoding 
    //Array Values
        $a1=array("name"=>"abc", "value"=>"def", "description"=>"ghi");
        $a2=array("name"=>"jkl", "value"=>"mno", "description"=>"pqr");
        $a3=array("name"=>"stu", "value"=>"wxy", "description"=>"zab");
    //Array of Value Arrays
        $info=array($a1, $a2, $a3);
        $result=array($a1, $a2, $a3);
        $stuff=array($a1, $a2, $a3);
    //The Main Enclosed Array
        $main=json_encode(array("info"=>$info, "result"=>$result, "stuff"=>$stuff));

    //Decoding  
    //Fetching the name from result's $a1 array
        $main_array=json_decode($main);
        echo $main_array->result[1]->name; //Displays jkl
```