# Is it possible to have more than one key reference the same value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, key, refactoring, code-cleanup

I'm wondering if it's possible to clean this code up a bit...I have an array of car categories and each key is a vehicle code. There are several vehicle codes that I am mapping to a particular category (ex. Small, Medium, Large). I've asked a similar question previously, but I'm not sure if it was clear so I simplified my question. *I'd like to keep this similar format, but wondering if it's possible to do something like this (so that I don't have to write "Small" more than once):*

```
        $categories = [
            'L...' => 'Luxury',
            'W...' => 'Luxury',
            'X...' => 'Specialty',

            'CB..', 'CC..', 'CD..' => 'Small' 
            // Is something like this possible to do within the $categories array ?
        ];
```

**Current Code:**

```
        $categories = [
            'L...' => 'Luxury',
            'W...' => 'Luxury',
            'X...' => 'Specialty',

            'CB..' => 'Small',
            'CC..' => 'Small',
            'CD..' => 'Small',
            'DB..' => 'Small',
            'DC..' => 'Small',
            'DD..' => 'Small',
            'EB..' => 'Small',
            'EC..' => 'Small',
            'ED..' => 'Small',
            'HB..' => 'Small',
            'HC..' => 'Small',
            'HD..' => 'Small',
            'MB..' => 'Small',
            'MC..' => 'Small',
            'MD..' => 'Small',
            'NB..' => 'Small',
            'NC..' => 'Small',
            'ND..' => 'Small',

            'IB..' => 'Medium',
            'IC..' => 'Medium',
            'ID..' => 'Medium',
            'JB..' => 'Medium',
            'JC..' => 'Medium',
            'JD..' => 'Medium',
            'RB..' => 'Medium',
            'RC..' => 'Medium',
            'RD..' => 'Medium',
            'SB..' => 'Medium',
            'SC..' => 'Medium',
            'SD..' => 'Medium',

            'FB..' => 'Large',
            'FC..' => 'Large',
            'FD..' => 'Large',
            'GB..' => 'Large',
            'GC..' => 'Large',
            'GD..' => 'Large',
            'PB..' => 'Large',
            'PC..' => 'Large',
            'PD..' => 'Large',
            'UB..' => 'Large',
            'UC..' => 'Large',
            'UD..' => 'Large',

            '.E..' => 'Sports', // Coupe
            '.F..' => 'SUV',
            '.G..' => 'SUV', // Crossover
            '.H..' => 'RV', // Motor Home
            '.J..' => 'Off-Road Vehicle',
            '.K..' => 'Commercial',
            '.L..' => 'Luxury', // Limousine
            '.M..' => 'Van', // Monospace
            '.N..' => 'Convertible', // Roadster
            '.P..' => 'Pickup Truck',
            '.Q..' => 'Pickup Truck',
            '.R..' => 'RV',
            '.S..' => 'Sports',
            '.T..' => 'Convertible',
            '.V..' => 'Van',
            '.W..' => 'Wagon',
            '.X..' => 'Specialty',
            '.Z..' => 'Specialty',

            '...C' => 'Electric',
            '...E' => 'Electric',
            '...H' => 'Hybrid',
            '...I' => 'Hybrid'
        ];
```

Comment: Why not use a multi-dimensional array, the other way around? e.g. `$categories = ['Luxury' => ['L','W'], 'Specialty' => ['X'] ... and so on ... ];`

Comment: Why are you storing this data in your code?

Comment: @CD001 Ah okay this is great - How would I be able to loop through each value if I do it this way?

Comment: Depends exactly what you're trying to do, you could use a [recursive array search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472779/recursive-array-search) to find the item you're after - though you'd probably be better off structuring the data differently initially, in a database or perhaps even XML file at a push, you've got more readily available features then.

Answer (score 2):

Following @CD001's comment, you can achieve this by inverting the array and storing the codes within the category, then with a little function just match its found and return the key/categorie.

```
<?php
$categories = [
    'Luxury' => [
        'L...',
        'W...'
    ],
    'Specialty' => [
        'X...',
        '.Z..',
        '.X..'
    ],
    'Sports' => [
        '.E..',
        '.S..'
    ],
    'SUV' => [
        '.F..',
        '.G..'
    ],
    'RV' => [
        '.H..',
        '.R..'
    ],
    'Off-Road Vehicle' => [
        '.J..'
    ],
    'Commercial' => [
        '.K..'
    ],
    'Van' => [
        '.M..',
        '.V..'
    ],
    'Convertible' => [
        '.N..',
        '.T..'
    ],
    'Pickup Truck' => [
        '.P..',
        '.Q..',
    ],
    'Wagon' => [
        '.W..'
    ],
    'Electric' => [
        '...C',
        '...E'
    ],
    'Hybrid' => [
        '...H',
        '...I'
    ],
    'Small' => [
        'CB..',
        'CC..',
        'CD..',
        'DB..',
        'DC..',
        'DD..',
        'EB..',
        'EC..',
        'ED..',
        'HB..',
        'HC..',
        'HD..',
        'MB..',
        'MC..',
        'MD..',
        'NB..',
        'NC..',
        'ND..'
    ],
    'Medium' => [
        'IB..',
        'IC..',
        'ID..',
        'JB..',
        'JC..',
        'JD..',
        'RB..',
        'RC..',
        'RD..',
        'SB..',
        'SC..',
        'SD..'
    ],
    'Large' => [
        'FB..',
        'FC..',
        'FD..',
        'GB..',
        'GC..',
        'GD..',
        'PB..',
        'PC..',
        'PD..',
        'UB..',
        'UC..',
        'UD..'
    ],
];

$getType = function($search) use ($categories) {
    foreach ($categories as $k => $v) {
        $key = array_search($search, $v);
        if ($key !== false) {
            return $k;
        }
    }
};

print_r(
    // Hybrid
    $getType('...H')
);
```

It's still a large array though, but at least your not repeating `Small`. You could remove the whitespace so its like:

```
<?php
$categories = [
    'Luxury' => [
        'L...', 'W...'
    ],
    'Specialty' => [
        'X...', '.Z..', '.X..'
    ],
    'Sports' => [
        '.E..', '.S..'
    ],
    'SUV' => [
        '.F..', '.G..'
    ],
    'RV' => [
        '.H..', '.R..'
    ],
    'Off-Road Vehicle' => [
        '.J..'
    ],
    ...
```

Or put them in a database, then it will be cleaner.

Edit: Huge thanks to @CD001

```
$getType = function($search, $bestMatch = false) use ($categories) { 
    $search = str_pad($search, 4, ".", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
    $out = []; 
    foreach ($categories as $k => $v) { 
        foreach ($v as $r) { 
            if (preg_match('/' . $r . '/', $search)) { 
                $out[] = $k; 
            }
        }
    }

    if ($bestMatch) {
        // work out best match by adding a count
        $out = array_count_values($out);
        // sort
        arsort($out);
        //return the best match
        $out = array_keys(array_slice($out, 0, 1))[0];
    } else {
        $out = array_values(array_unique($out));
    }
    return $out;
};

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Luxury
    [1] => Convertible
)
*/
print_r(
    $getType('LTAR')
);

//Luxury
print_r(
    $getType('LTAR', true)
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful! My goal with this is to return the category name so if if the Vehicle Code is "MCAR" I would like it to return "Small" because M and C are the first and second letters ['MC...']. If I wanted to compare MCAR to ['MC..'] within the Small Category, any ideas how to achieve this with this approach? Thanks again!!

Comment: Interesting/possible, comment with a couple more codes can test something, is there any situation which MC means say Medium

Comment: LTAR = BOTH Luxury and Convertible (because L is the first letter and T is the second letter...there will overlap in certain cases like this), FBAR = Large, XXXC = Electric (because C is the last letter), PQXX = Pickup Truck (because Q is the second letter)..Does this make sense?

Comment: Since `.` is a wildcard in RegExp you could possibly treat the values as patterns: `LTAR` would be matched, in that case, by both `/L.../` and `/.T../` - the function could return an array something like `['Luxury','Convertible']` denoting both categories. Since we're working with a **very** limited set of possible values we might get away with it (there don't appear to be any overlaps).

Comment: Ah that's a good idea. Could you possibly show me an example of how to match using regex? I think I may actually move this information to a database as you suggested :)

Comment: Just tweaking the `$getType` function a bit ... `$getType = function($search) use ($categories) {
 $out = [];
    foreach ($categories as $k => $v) {
  foreach($v as $r) {
   if(preg_match('/' . $r . '/', $search)) {
    $out[] = $k;
   }
  }
    }
 return $out;
};`

Comment: One more thing I just realized, can we make it so that if the overlap is the same we only insert one of them into the array (Example: http://prntscr.com/gt87o5) ...Specialty should only be here once. Thanks!

Comment: @CD001 Nice, I was having a ponder at trying todo it without regex, but im obviously having the issue of keeping best state between arrays and matching the best match of a multiple but with some tweeking of yours it can easily return the best match. Ill update

Comment: Just change the return to `return array_unique($out);` - will remove duplicates from the array. @MichaelAlterio

Comment: @LawrenceCherone ... I spent too much time using Perl back in the day so I tend to fall back on RegExps too easily I'm afraid ;)

Comment: @MichaelAlterio not sure what you want to do with XXXC = Electricity if fewer matches are more important then more matches remove the `arsort($out);` other then that you're need to make a choice, add a bypass in the function or store all permutations in db ;p

Comment: I like array_unique but I'm noticing it skips the [1] index...can we make it so that the index does not skip? See: http://prntscr.com/gt8gzy :) ...This is example for XXXC ...I guess I'm wondering instead of using array_unique, we only insert into the array if value is not in array?

Comment: @MichaelAlterio do `array_values()` to reset its index.

Comment: Like this? return array_values(array_unique($out));

Comment: yeah, ive changed the function to return best match, and array_unique'ed array with reset index.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you should rearrange this array depends on what you need to do with it. If you need to look up categories based on vehicle codes, *you should not change it*.

The way it is now, you can get a category quickly and efficiently.

```
$category = $categories[$vehicle_code];
```

If you change it to a multidimensional structure, this lookup will be inherently slower and more complex. There are different ways to do it, but it will require some version of looping all the sub-arrays of codes until you find the one that has your code in it.

```
foreach ($categories as $cat => $codes) {
    if (in_array($vehicle_code, $codes)) {
        $category = $cat;
        break;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you need to show all vehicle codes for a certain category, then the multidimensional structure will work better for that.

If you need to do both of those things, or various other things that require defined relationships between vehicle codes and categories, you should consider storing this data in a database. Personally, I think you should consider that anyway. This looks like potentially dynamic data, and if you store it in your application code, you'll have a new version of your application any time you add or update vehicle codes or categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_fill_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) like

```
<?php

$aKeys = ['A','B','C'];

$aResult = array_fill_keys ( $aKeys , 'small' );

print_r($aResult);
```