# Find specific value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a search of the digit one [1] in multidimensional array. It does work using a standard array [$array_1], but not when there are embedded arrays [$array_2] and [$array_3].

At the very end of the script you find what I have tried.

**Wanted behaviour:**

The search to return a value that indicates if the value was found.
It is fine with either the index position, alternatively returning the amount of digits or repetetive numbers of found digits.

My plan is to move the result into a variable and check if the results is null. If null means it did not find any search result. I am using null because zero [0] could refer to the index position.

```
<pre>

<?php

$search_for_value = 1;

/**
 * ---------------------------------
 * Array.
 * ---------------------------------
 */

$array_1 = [3, 2, 1];

/**
 * ---------------------------------
 * Multidimensional arrays.
 * ---------------------------------
 */

/**
  *  Value 1 is exists in the array.
 */

$array_2 = [
        [2],
        [1]
];


echo ("-- array_2 ---\n\n");
print_r($array_2);

/**
 *  Value 1 is missing in the array.
 */

$array_3 = [
        [4],
        [5]
];

echo ("-- array_3 ---\n\n");
print_r($array_3);


/**
 * Functions
 */
 function find_value($search_for_value, $array_selected) {
     return(array_search($search_for_value, $array_selected));
 };


 /**
  * ---------------------------------
  * Searches
  * ---------------------------------
  */

 // Search for value in array_1

$array_selected = $array_1;

 print_r(
     find_value(
         $search_for_value, $array_selected
     )
 );

 // Search for value in array_2

 $array_selected = $array_2;

 print_r(                                               # <==== Not working.
     find_value(
         $search_for_value, $array_selected
     )
 );

?>
```

Comment: You need to implement a recursive search. Possibly something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/28472779/296555.

Comment: You could use is_array to check whether there is a sub array and adapt your find if one layer of depth is enough. But you could also do this recursively as already proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use in_array with splat operator,
Below is for multidimensional arrays

```
$temp = array_merge(...$array_2);
var_dump(in_array(2, $temp));
$temp = array_merge(...$array_3);
var_dump(in_array(2, $temp));
```

for 1D arrays,

you can directly check `in_array($value_to_search, $array_1);`

I am exposing array to their value level so they flatten up.
Now I just checked with in_array whether it exists in an array or not.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/nWEbl).

Comment: But what if you want to just search a single multidimensional array?

Comment: this solution does not consider a 1D array

Comment: Still you can remove `...$array2` or `...$array3` from snippet.

Comment: for 1d, in_array is enough. No need of my code at all.

Comment: You mean you need generalised function which will work for both 1D and 2D both?

Comment: I don't get you, whhaaat? Pardon, I am expecting technicality but feeling I am unclear.

Comment: Should that be `$search_for_value`?

Comment: Check this [demo](https://3v4l.org/Pk9mv) and please let me know what should be what!

Comment: @Drakula To clarify I was looking how to search in one 2D array. Your answer shows how to search in many 2D arrays and how to search in one 1D array. I think your answer fulfills the purpose and anyhow covers the scope. I will go ahead and approve.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive function that returns a boolean indicating if the value was found. The majority of this function was taken from [Recursive array_search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28472779/296555).

```
/**
 * Returns a boolean indicating if the needle is found in the haystack.
 * @param $needle
 * @param $haystack
 * @return bool
 */
function find_value($needle, $haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {

        if ($needle === $value || (is_array($value) && find_value($needle, $value) !== false)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```